# MS SQL stored procedure fails when called from php 5 halfway through

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have been bashing my head against a wall for several hours now and I suspect that the answer is a simple one if you know where to look.

I have a compiled stored procedure in MS SQL 2005 which works perfectly. I have tested it and have no errors whatsoever.

However when I call the same procedure from my PHP include file shown here the stored procedure seems to start running (my mssql trace shows the call to be made correctly) then stops half way through. Sometimes I get 10 out of 15 records updated. Other times I get 5 out of 14.

If I copy the command that was run from the trace window and run it directly in MS SQL management studio it works perfectly. This leads me to think it is some sort of timeout or am I closing the connection before the procedure is run so MS SQL 2005 thinks it should be terminated?

```
<?php
session_start();
require ('../includes/config.inc.php'); 
require('../includes/mssql.php');

function include_booking($box, $offeredtolocumid, $surgery, $rate) {
    $dbc2 = mssql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    $q2 = "exec WEB_Surgery_Box_OfferBoxtoLocum '".$box."', '".$offeredtolocumid."', '".$surgery."'";
    $myresult = mssql_query($q2 ,$dbc2);

}     
    /* set out document type to text/javascript instead of text/html */
    header("Content-type: text/javascript");

    $offeredtolocumid = $_GET["locumid"];
    //$rate = $_GET["rate"];
    $rate = 15.99;
    $surgery = $_SESSION['surgeryid'];
    $box = $_SESSION['currentbox'];

    include_booking($box, $offeredtolocumid, $surgery, $rate);

    ?>
```

I am new to the PHP / MS SQL bit so I understand that the code above is not perfect by any means.

I have many other procedure calls that work without problem. Just this one doesnt. 
The MS SQL server will take on average 0.1 second to complete this procedure.
I hope someone has an answer.

Thanks
Neil

Comment: Before anyone spends too much time on this I may already have a solution. I may have missed a SET NO COUNT on which of course is upsetting PHP no end even if the SQL Studio doesnt mind it.
Thanks if you read it though. I shall test tomorrow and report on my possible stupidity!

Answer (score 0):

After much testing today and removing the SET NO COUNT option which then crashed the procedure again I am confident that this was the problem.

So to clarify. When calling an MS SQL Stored Procedure from PHP I should use the SET NO COUNT to prevent anything undesireable from being returned.

Thanks.